# Writing from an Excel row onto a Word docx

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have an Excel worksheet with words in each cell. I wanted to write this row
onto a Word document.

The macro worked pefectly the first time.

When the macro is run, the docx file has already been created but not opened.

I rubbed out the text in the word document and closed it

Then I ran the Excel macro again and got a message saying that the document
was locked for editing by myself.

There was an option, then, to create a local copy. I did this and eventually
I got the text on to the Word document.

What is going on, please ?

I simply don't understand what this "locked for editing" is.

I think the relevant lines of code are :

```
 Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim oRng As Word.Range 
destfilename = "E:\......\Dummy_Script.docx"
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(destfilename)
'
' TextA is a string with the text of the row
'
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
oRng.Text = TextA
```

"Code"

Comment: if you close excel , open it again and run macro the same thing happens?

Comment: This is probably because you are creating a new instance of Word and not closing the document or instance properly, so it is still open. If you then try to open it in another instance, you'll get a File In Use dialog. Can you show the full code, or at least everything where you create/open/save/close/quit `objDoc` and `objWord`?

Comment: There are two things (1) Yes, I had not closed the document but when I corrected this (2) I started getting Error 462 problems If anyone else has this problem, I recommend reading            https://anictteacher.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/vba-error-462-explained-and-resolved.pdf  This cleared up the matter.